# Brightness level stuck at minimum after upgrading to Android 5.1.1

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, sony-xperia-z, screen-brightness

I have Sony Xperia Z (C6603, 10.7.A.0.222) and the brightness level is stuck at minimum after update to 5.1.1.

I have tried:

- sensor test - light sensor is OK.
- set brightness via ADB (`settings put system screen_brightness 200`) - didn't work.
- using brightness control apps (like LUX for example) - didn't work.

Using stock ROM without root, any apps or functions that could set brightness to low for saving battery are either uninstalled or turned off? Any suggestions?

Comment: This is probably one of the oddest problems I've seen here. Have you tried a factory reset? Not really ideal, but worth a shot.

Comment: Tried it, my thoughts are it must be either hardware problem or this ROM problem.. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can flash the rom but chances are that there is hardware damage.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me on my galaxy note20 3 weeks ago.  My screen went pretty dark.  After a hour or so i saw on settings blue light filter was on.  I did not turn it on. I had to shut it off then reset the phone.